# OpenidDict 4.0 + MSAL.js fails for Code flow + PKCE due to sending scopes

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, msal.js, openiddict

**Problem**

Openididct v4 started declining the PKCE's Access Token request ([RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636), when the client exchanges the authorization code) if the client passes `scopes` ([ref to the line in the code](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/a31209dbc2249110e10ae9799c2fc03b802c752c/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerHandlers.Exchange.cs#L740) enforcing it). It wasn't the case for v3.x

However, the [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) implementation has what they call "*hybrid flow*" ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-id-token-as-well-or-hybrid-flow)) that mixes the implicit grant with the authorization code flow, and it sends `scopes` in when exchanging the authorization code.

**Example**

Request from MSAL.js:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:5003/connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' \
--data 'client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:5003&scope=openid%20profile&code={THE_CODE}&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.21.0&x-client-OS=&x-client-CPU=&x-ms-lib-capability=retry-after, h429&x-client-current-telemetry=5|865,0,,,|,&x-client-last-telemetry=5|0|865,33365111-6e2e-4707-946c-e93b095f6c1e|invalid_request|1,0&code_verifier=jJdT8dsU&grant_type=authorization_code&client_info=1&client-request-id=99933333-cdd4-4991-8dcb-1a28f3a0669d'
```

Response from Openiddict:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The 'scope' parameter is not valid in this context.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2074"
}
```

**Question**

Is there a way of relaxing this particular check?

IMHO, the Openiddict rejection, in this case, is too rigid behaviour, where a warning would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controversial check for `scopes` when exchanging the authorization code was added in OpenIdDict v4 ([link to the commit](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/commit/ffd47678fcd8f76c39e38c655820bc171f9e90ca)). As you can see from [the code](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/3dc3e010097c96fb6e47f7bacd1cb33afe1ddba0/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerHandlers.Exchange.cs#L713):

- all it does is rejecting code requests that contain a "scope" parameter;
- it's built as an `EventHandler` that makes it easy to add/remove from the pipeline (and yes, it's added in `Exchange.DefaultHandlers`, so it's ON by default).

Hence, it's safe to remove the handler by adding this line to `AddServer()`:

```
options.RemoveEventHandler(OpenIddictServerHandlers.Exchange.ValidateScopeParameter.Descriptor)
```

Here's an example of what the registration of the OpenIddict token server services in the DI container may look like (see more in [my GitHub example](https://github.com/AKlaus/Transparent-Auth-Gateway)):

```
// Register the OpenIddict services
services.AddOpenIddict()
        // Register the OpenIddict server components.
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
            // Enable the authorization and token endpoints
            options 
                    .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                    .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                    .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                    .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
                    .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()

                // Remove a default guard that rejects auth code requests that contain a "scope" parameter
                    .RemoveEventHandler(OpenIddictServerHandlers.Exchange.ValidateScopeParameter.Descriptor);

                // Other settings go here

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.  
                    .UseAspNetCore();
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, the MSAL.js implementation has what they call "hybrid flow" (docs) that mixes the implicit grant with the authorization code flow, and it sends scopes in when exchanging the authorization code.

The hybrid flow is not a Microsoft-specific concept but a standard OpenID Connect flow defined in [the OpenID Connect Core 1.0 specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridFlowAuth).

The second part of the flow - the token request - is defined by [section 3.3.3.1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridTokenRequest):

```http
When using the Hybrid Flow, Token Requests are made in the same manner
as for the Authorization Code Flow, as defined in Section 3.1.3.1.
```

Here's what [section 3.1.3.1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest) says:

```http
A Client makes a Token Request by presenting its Authorization Grant
(in the form of an Authorization Code) to the Token Endpoint using the
grant_type value authorization_code, as described in Section 4.1.3 of
OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749]. If the Client is a Confidential Client, then it MUST
authenticate to the Token Endpoint using the authentication method
registered for its client_id, as described in Section 9.

The Client sends the parameters to the Token Endpoint using the HTTP
POST method and the Form Serialization, per Section 13.2, as described
in Section 4.1.3 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749].

The following is a non-normative example of a Token Request
(with line wraps within values for display purposes only):

POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW

grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb
```

And here's what section 4.1.3 of the OAuth 2.0 specification says:

```http
4.1.3.  Access Token Request

   The client makes a request to the token endpoint by sending the
   following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP
   request entity-body:

   grant_type
         REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "authorization_code".

   code
         REQUIRED.  The authorization code received from the
         authorization server.

   redirect_uri
         REQUIRED, if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the
         authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1, and their
         values MUST be identical.

   client_id
         REQUIRED, if the client is not authenticating with the
         authorization server as described in Section 3.2.1.
```

As you can see, the `scope` parameter is not a standard thing in the second part of the authorization code or hybrid flows: since this parameter is uncalled for in these flows, OpenIddict rejects it to indicate you're doing something invalid/non-standard.

While using MSAL.js with non-Microsoft implementation should probably be avoided (oidc-client-ts would likely be a better option in this case), it's of course possible to work around this compliance issue server-side.

The solution you ended up with certainly works but **I wouldn't recommend it** as additional logic may be eventually added to the built-in `ValidateScopeParameter` handler.

Instead, I'd recommend creating a custom event handler that removes the invalid `scope` parameter from `grant_type=authorization_code` token requests.

```cs
options.AddEventHandler<ExtractTokenRequestContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseInlineHandler(static context =>
    {
        // The "scope" parameter is uncalled for for grant_type=authorization_code
        // requests. To ensure OpenIddict won't reject token requests containing a
        // "scope" parameter, this parameter is removed from the request instance.
        if (context.Request is not null && context.Request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType())
        {
            context.Request.RemoveParameter(Parameters.Scope);
        }

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    });

    builder.SetOrder(int.MaxValue);
});
```